# create 5 colums in a list in a button click in sharepoint?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have a list with some fields and a button, if a user enter a numeric value in one field and then  click a button then I need to generate 5 columns automatically in each click of the button ??

NB:The button click must be equal to the numeric value specified in the field just above the button

Comment: Not sure if you want to actually create new columns on button click **OR** just display the already added columns on button click in the form.

Comment: I need to display a set of new columns in each click

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain HTML table and JavaScript to achieve this. I will try to give you high level instructions for the same -

1. Add a content editor webpart to your form, and then create a html
   table using plain HTML. Add the field that gives you the number of
   columns you want to the html table. Insert the button to generate
   columns here. This needs to be done in your NewForm.aspx page of the
   list
2. Create a javascript function, that adds the new columns based on
   input from Step 2 using insertRow() method
3. Take the data from the newly created columns, and concatenate them
   together in some form of delimiter(#,$$,etc)
4. Finally save all these data into your list using JS methods for
   sharepoint
5. For displaying the data, create a new JS method in the
   document.ready() method, that queries the ID in the URL for
   EditForm.aspx and DispForm.aspx pages and displays the data in the
   HTML tables created in the respective aspx pages, using similar
   method in Step 1